# Spark Scala search via RegEx to preform character injection

Tags: regex, apache-spark

Dataframe Generation Script:

```
  val inputDF = spark.sql("select 'abcd1234efgh' as test_column")
  val preferredOutputDF = spark.sql("select 'abcd*1234efgh' as test_column")
```

Goal:
I am trying to build out a RegEx search that in the output location of the replace it will just inject a character in the found string. In the above case I am looking for four digits and when found appending a * to it. I have included a bunch of test cases below.

What I have tried:

```
//Replaces the one area with what is within the second column
////First row output
//////abcd*[0-9]efgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'[0-9]{4}','*[0-9]') as test_column_output", "test_column"))

//Replaces the one area with just *'s
////First row output
//////abcd~*efgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'[0-9]{4}','*') as test_column_output", "test_column"))

//Still confused how this worked and in what scenarios why you would want to use it
////First row output
//////abcdabcd1234efghefgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column, '[0-9]{4}', *) as test_column_output", "test_column"))

////First row output
//////abc*234efgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'(d)[0-9]','*') as test_column_output", "test_column")

////First row output
//////abcd1234efgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'[d](0-9)','*') as test_column_output", "test_column")

////First row output
//////abc*234efgh
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'[d][0-9]','*') as test_column_output", "test_column")

////ERROR
//////org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input '(' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 40)
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'(d)(0-9)','*'(d)[0-9]) as test_column_output", "test_column")

////ERROR
//////org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input '(' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 40)
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'[d](0-9)','*'(d)(0-9)) as test_column_output", "test_column")

////ERROR
//////org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input '(' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 40)
inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'(d)(0-9)','*'[d][0-9]) as test_column_output", "test_column")
```

Comment: Try using a capturing group `regexp_replace(test_column,"([0-9]{4})","$1*"") as test_column_output", "test_column"))` Note that `[0-9]{4}` will match 4 digits without any further rules or boundaries.

Comment: Thats it your a hero. inputDF.selectExpr("regexp_replace(test_column,'([0-9]{4})','*$1') as test_column_output").show(100,false). The reason I changed the demo spreadsheet to be [0-9]{4} was when I did the function with only a * for replacement without 's and had a kinda hilarious output.

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you want to put what you placed above as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[d]` will match the character `d` using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which can be omitted. Using  `(d)` will capture `d` in a capturing group and `[0-9]{4}` will match 4 digits.

What you can do instead is capture 4 digits in a group and in the replacement reference that group using `$1`. Then you could prepend or append a `*` to it.

```
regexp_replace(test_column,'([0-9]{4})','*$1')
```